# Edit with [Icon mode]

Tags: context-menu, regedit

I already add in my contextual menu "Edit with ..." in my particular case Edit with Photoshop.

[My contextual menu is this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8jss.png)

All working for me, but is less intuitive than Edit with Notepad ++ at example, because for me missing a icon, so every time i must take more care before open with..

**Anyone know how to add icon in contextual like my Notepad++ app?**

P.s I read similar question about menu, but nobody add the icon, so don't mark for duplicate, because I don't look simple add in menu (I already did)